# Can someone tell how I need to declare user model in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

It is my User model, is it correct? Can I add methods????

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  login: string;
  hash: string;
  salt: string;
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
  sname: string;
  phone: string;
  addTime: string;
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

Comment: yes you can add getter setters to , if you are just want for binding go for interfaces it is much better

Comment: @RahulSingh: can You show me some example, )

Comment: I am a little worried that you would keep password (login?), hash and salt there.. And if it's correct or not  depends on your project requirements. Otherwise you can add getters, setters but also much more

Comment: @Vega: I would replace hash & salt with password...

Comment: Please learn basics before you ask quesitons here. This site is meant to help solve specific problems.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko: Yes sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a just a prototype i copied

```
export class Model{ //something like this for getter and setters and also other methods 
    private _keyValue: number;
    private _computedValue: number;

    getKeyValue(): number{
        return this._keyValue;
    }

    setKeyValue(value: number){
        this._keyValue = value;
    }

    getComputedValue(): number{
        return this._computedValue;
    }
    customeMethod(){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it...))))